# Ansible json_query converts JSON data to Python data types

Tags: ansible

I am reading and querying a local JSON file. That file contains information which is needed to create HTTP POST requests. The local file looks like this:

```
{
  "ctfd_api_key": "API_KEY",
  "url": "http://172.19.0.1:8000",
  "hosts": [
    {
      "host": "host1",
      "hashing_algo": "md5",
      "team": {
        "name": "testteam",
        "password": "f0475264f5b88474376b149968e26b8d",
        "email": "testteam@mail.com",
        "secret": null,
        "website": null,
        "affiliation": null,
        "country": null,
        "bracket": null,
        "hidden": false,
        "banned": false,
        "captain_id": null,
        "members": [
          {
            "name": "test1",
            "password": "test1",
            "email": "test1@mail.com",
            "type": "user",
            "secret": null,
            "website": null,
            "affiliation": null,
            "country": null,
            "bracket": null,
            "hidden": false,
            "banned": false,
            "verified": true,
            "team_id": null
          },
          {
            "name": "test2",
            "password": "test2",
            "email": "tes12@mail.com",
            "type": "user",
            "secret": null,
            "website": null,
            "affiliation": null,
            "country": null,
            "bracket": null,
            "hidden": false,
            "banned": false,
            "verified": true,
            "team_id": null
          }
        ]
      },
      "challenges": [
        ....
      ]
    },
    {
       ...
    }
  ]
}
```

I read the config file in my playbook as follows:- name: 'initiate ctfd state based on read config'

```
  hosts: 'localhost'
  roles:
    - user
  vars:
    url: "{{  cfg.stdout | from_json | json_query('url') }}"
    ctfd_api_key: "{{ cfg.stdout | from_json | json_query('ctfd_api_key') }}"
    hosts: "{{ cfg.stdout | from_json | json_query('hosts') }}"
```

For debugging purpose I then printed each host. A value which previously was null should be returned as null. This returns the expected values.

```
- name: 'debug teams'
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: '{{ item }}'
  loop: '{{ hosts }}'
```

If I query the variable to flatten the team list I do not receive the expected values. A null value returns as no value at all (None). A false value gets returned as False. Both of these values would then be used in an HTTP post request which obiously would not be a valid request and fail.

```
- name: 'debug teams'
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: |-
      team: {{ item.0.name }}
      name: {{ item.1.name }}
      pswd: {{ item.1.password }}
      shouldBeNull: {{ item.1.website }}
      shouldBeFalse: {{ item.1.banned }}
  loop: "{{ hosts | community.general.json_query('[].team.{name: name, members: members}') | subelements('members') }}"
```

one example output would be:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'name': 'testteam', 'members': [{'name': 'test1', 'password': 'test1', 'email': 'test1@mail.com', 'type': 'user', 'secret': None, 'website': None, 'affiliation': None, 'country': None, 'bracket': None, 'hidden': False, 'banned': False, 'verified': True, 'team_id': None}, {'name': 'test2', 'password': 'test2', 'email': 'test2@mail.com', 'type': 'user', 'secret': None, 'website': None, 'affiliation': None, 'country': None, 'bracket': None, 'hidden': False, 'banned': False, 'verified': True, 'team_id': None}]}, {'name': 'test1', 'password': 'test1', 'email': 'test1@mail.com', 'type': 'user', 'secret': None, 'website': None, 'affiliation': None, 'country': None, 'bracket': None, 'hidden': False, 'banned': False, 'verified': True, 'team_id': None}]) => {
    "msg": "team: testteam\nname: test1\npswd: test1\nshouldBeNull: \nshouldBeFalse: False"
}
```

My expected result would have been:

```
  ...
  => {
        "msg": "team: testteam, name: test1, pswd: test1, shouldBeNull: null, shouldBeFalse: false"
    }
```

I tried casting the values to boolean but that did not change anything. How can I achieve my goal?